# activating conda environment pipes unknown script to command line

Tags: conda, environment

I'm new and learning how to use Conda environments on windows 11. after days of reading and setting up a conda environment to start learning Ai, a weird problem started showing whenever I launch the Anaconda Command Prompt and activate the environment (named ailab) , basically a long script is automatically piped into the command line (shown below partial capture). also this behavior happens after running an INSTALL command. I am using Anaconda on Windows 11.

I am reluctant to recreate/reinstall the environment as I spent a lot of time to get the right env plan/dependencies to run pytorch on my GPU and installed many other consistent packages. any clue what is going on in this env and how to fix it?

Thanks !

###### below is a copy of Anaconda Command Prompt terminal screen

base) C:\Windows\System32>conda activate ailab

C:\Windows\System32>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Windows\System32>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Windows\System32>SET "VS_VERSION=15.0"

C:\Windows\System32>SET "VS_MAJOR=15"

C:\Windows\System32>SET "VS_YEAR=2017"

C:\Windows\System32>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"

C:\Windows\System32>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"

C:\Windows\System32>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\bin\vcruntime140.dll"

C:\Windows\System32>set "CXX=cl.exe"

C:\Windows\System32>set "CC=cl.exe"

C:\Windows\System32>set "VSINSTALLDIR="

C:\Windows\System32>set "NEWER_VS_WITH_OLDER_VC=0"

C:\Windows\System32>for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -version [15.0,16.0) -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i" )

C:\Windows\System32>if not exist "" (for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VC.Tools.141.x86.x64 -property installationPath`) do (
set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i"
set "NEWER_VS_WITH_OLDER_VC=1"
) )

C:\Windows\System32>if not exist "" (for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64 -property installationPath`) do (
set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i"
set "NEWER_VS_WITH_OLDER_VC=1"
) )

I tried to look for this script and googled the issue without luck.

###### update

I searched for the script text in my env folders and found it in a script called **"vs2017_compiler_vars.bat"** in the directory

**C:\Users\misha\anaconda3\envs\ailab\pkgs\vs2017_win-64-19.16.27033-hddac466_16\etc\conda\activate.d**

The first line in the batch file was "@@echo on" so I set it "@@echo off" and fixed the issue (not sure why it was set to "echo on" by the environment")

Now I am getting the following message when I am activating the environment

**(base) C:\Windows\System32>activate ailab**

**Windows SDK version found as: "10.0.22621.0"
"NEWER_VS_WITH_OLDER_VC=0"
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.**

it seems an issue with visual studio install, so I tried to install it with

conda install -c anaconda vs2017_win-64

but didn't help and the "@@echo on" problem came back. Any thoughts on how to get out of the rabbit hole ?